# Проблема вывода $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите где я совершил ошибку, что у меня выходит ошибка: "Now the error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Вот кусок кода в котором проблема:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Chart/GetVotings',
    }).data (function (votings) {
        votings = $.parseJSON(votings);
        $: each(votings, function (index, data) {
            chartData.labels.push(data.name);
            chartData.datasets[0].data.push(data.voice);
        });
    });
});
```

Вот весь код:

```
<canvas id="ChartVote" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Chart/GetVotings',
        }).done(function (votings) {
            console.log(votings);
            votings = $.parseJSON(votings);
            $: each(votings, function (index, data) {
                chartData.labels.push(data.name);
                chartData.datasets[0].data.push(data.voice);
            });
        });
    });

    var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartVote");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: В строке `votings = $.parseJSON(votings);`? Добавьте `console.log(votings);` перед этой строкой и вставьте то, что выведено в консоль, в Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).data is not a function, поменял строку .data (function (votings)  на .done (function (votings), как в примере что я нашел. Даже данные частично начали подгружаться, но не выводиться все еще в график и ошибка опять стала "Now the error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: в какой строке происходит ошибка?

Comment: Вот как раз в этом и проблема что указывает на 1 строку ))

Comment: не на строку, а на позицию - имеется в виду текст (данные) ответа, который код пытается обработать как JSON - покажите уже, что Вы возвращаете из `ChartController.GetVotings`.

Comment: Object
DateVote
:
"/Date(1473355320537)/"
Id
:
30
IpAdress
:
"::1"
Name
:
"Родина"
Voice
:
1

Comment: ну, это не JSON - http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, правда не полноценное пока что, нужна еще сделать чтоб выводить лишь уникальные Name и выводить итоги Voice по каждому Name.

Ну а пока что вот рабочий вариант:

```
    <canvas id="ChartVote" class="ChartVotings" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetVotings","Chart")',
        }).done(function (votings) {
            var labelsArray = [];
            var dataArray = [];
            $.each(votings, function (index, data) {
                labelsArray.push(data.Name);
                dataArray.push(data.Voice);
            });
            renderChart(labelsArray, dataArray);
        });
    });
    function renderChart(labels, voice) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartVote");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes', data: voice,
                    backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: { beginAtZero: true }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```